# How many white horses were there in the chariot of Arjuna in mahabharatha war?

Tags: mahabharata

How many white horses were there in the chariot of Arjuna in Mahabharata ? 4 or 5 ? Some pictures showing 5 and some others showing 4 ? What is the exact number? It will be great if you add some pictures/quotes ?

Comment: There were four, looking for authentic sources to confirm

Comment: No point in asking such things. This is similar to asking "What would be the exact height of Hanuman?". It doesn't make sense. VTCed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a trivial information and not helpful.

Comment: @AnkitSharma This might be trivia, but that is typically not a reason to close things on Stack Exchange sites. I have voted to leave this question open.

Comment: @AwalGarg If the scriptures at some point stated the exact height of Hanuman (or, indeed, if there was even just some good reason to _expect_ that the scriptures stated the exact height of Hanuman), that would be a perfectly fine question. Likewise, I think this is a perfectly fine question.

Comment: @senshin Exactly, ***iff*** the condition you define was valid, this would have been valid.

Comment: It should be 5 if the horses represent the 5 senses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I commented, Arjuna's chariot had four white horses... Their respective names were

- Saibya
- Sugriva
- Meghapuspa
- Balahaka

[Reference](http://www.dharmakshetra.com/literature/horses.html)

[image: Arjuna's Chariot]

<sup>Image Credits : [dharmakshetra.com](http://www.dharmakshetra.com/literature/horses.html)</sup>

---

As you commented, am not sure about why some of the paintings show five horses so I searched for it and I found a nice thought [written by Vijay Shanker](http://qna.rediff.com/questions-and-answers/how-many-horses-were-there-for-arjuna-s-chariot-th/7785448/answers/7788104) who says

> May be with the
>   purpose of conveying a symbolic message that our body being a
>   Kurushetra battlefield where an ongoing fight between "Dharam" and
>   Adharam" keeps on going can only be won if we keep a proper control
>   over our Five Panchendriyas - eyes, ears, nose, tongue, skin, which
>   keeps us distracted from our right path. Krishna might be representing
>   our "Vivek " or "consciousness" of our body controlling our Five
>   panchendriyas represented by five horses to lead us to win over the
>   wrongdoings and win the final battle

Comment: @AnkitSharma Finding one, but am sure they were 4

Comment: You can also see a lot of pictures with 5 horses. Can you give the answer for that too?

Comment: @KiranRS Added..

Comment: You do realize this answer (AND the question) are somewhat... erm, not of use, don't you? Next question in line would be, how tall was Hanuman actually? Doesn't make sense does it?

Comment: @AwalGarg Ankit had a similar view over this, I didn't close voted for this question as some paintings do depict 5 horses where other depicts 4

Comment: We know it is legitimate to put our opinion, so I will vote to close (considering that you say another user is in agreement to this). But, I thought I should first fire it here...

Comment: @AwalGarg Sure..

Comment: Um.. those names are the names of **Krishna's** horses, not Arjuna's.
Reference: Amarakosha, Svargavarga.

Comment: Wow, didnt know their names were recorded too!

Answer (score 2):

As a chariot of war, "Kapi Dhwaja" was certainly a quadriga (drawn by 4 horses).
At that time, chariot of war where build for fast movement and efficiency. Therefore, it was probably build to be light in weight, which also implies 2 wheels only (instead of 4).

Having said that, we have to consider that every elements is symbolic. Some say 5 horses, because they represent our 5 senses that needs to be controlled. Some say 4 horses, because they represent our 4 basic emotions (i.e.: fear, joy, anger and sadness) that needs to be controlled.

They are controlled, by Krishna which represents "knowledge/wisdom" or "gnosis" as the "solar logos".

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! You should cite sources.